# ASP.NET MVC 5 Url Rewriting to encompass all actions in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routes

I would like to know if it's possible to write a rule in the Route.Config file that can encompass all actions within a single controller? I have read [this article](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/understanding-url-rewriting-and-url-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-mvc5-with-examples) but it's a little bit above me (I have just started with url rewriting and routing and the terminology is not familiar).

I have managed to change one of my actions from `mydomain.co.za/Trainee/Action?id=123` to `mydomain.co.za/Trainee/Action/123` but I was hoping to be able to encompass all actions in the Trainee controller, such that you can have one rule to produce `Trainee/Action1/123` or `Trainee/Action2/123` This is the code I used:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ActionRewrite",
            url: "Trainee/Action/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Trainee", action = "Action" }
        );
```

On a side note, is it possible to hide the parameters in a URL as well, such that you can simply have mydomain.co.za/Action/ no matter what the user is doing?

Comment: I would post the side note as a second question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ActionRewrite",
            url: "Trainee/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Trainee", action = {action} }
        );
```

- Bear in mind that you can use wildcards your url match.
- If you wanted you can specify that the {id} paramater remain optional which means it will also match actions that do not specify parameters.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick! I never knew that you could specify your action as a 'parameter' as it were. Thank you.

Comment: @barnacle.m yes it's quite flexible. For truly custom routing you can have a look at implementing a custom controller factory where you can have access to the route data collection. Plenty of examples around. Glad it works

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one ..
Url Rewiring in using custom id and name .**
**Add in app startup  Route config .**

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

`routes.MapRoute(
          name: "contactus",
          url: "contactus",
          defaults: new { Controller = "Cms", action = "Index", id = (int)Common.CMSContactUs },
           namespaces: new[] { "QZero.Controllers" }
      );
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "aboutus",
           url: "aboutus",
           defaults: new { Controller = "Cms", action = "Index", id = (int)Common.CMSAboutUs },
            namespaces: new[] { "QZero.Controllers" }
       );
        routes.MapRoute(
       name: "useragreement",
       url: "useragreement",
       defaults: new { Controller = "Cms", action = "Index", id = (int)Common.CMSUserAgreement },
        namespaces: new[] { "QZero.Controllers" }
   );
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           namespaces: new[] { "QZero.Controllers" }
       );

    }
}`